# convert string to boolean and compare with if condition in js

Tags: javascript

I have an attribute where I have got condition .I took that condition from tag's attribute now I want place that condition in if block and get result.

my code:-

```
 <div myCondition="1 == 2" id="hey"></a>
 <script>
  var a = document.getElementById('hey');
  var x = a.getAttribute('myCondition');
  if(x){
    console.log('accepted')
  }else{
    console.log('not accepted')
  }
</script>
```

above program should return not accepted
value of myCondition attribute can be very complex for example:-

```
'hello' == 'hello'
 5>1  etc
```

Comment: use === instead

Comment: Why are you storing conditions in attributes rather than in JavaScript / server-side code?

Comment: I don't know which one wins the *bad practices* contest: the question, that mixes presentation with data, or the accepted answer, that uses `eval`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is the [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function. As it says in the provided link:

> The `eval()` function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

So, you can change your code like this:

```
if( eval(x) ){
  console.log('accepted')
}else{
  console.log('not accepted')
}
```

---

P.S: That being said, I don't think doing it like this really safe.